# Special - Chinese characters in string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring, chinese-locale, nsstringencoding

I am doing language translation in code.

```
self.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Q%ld", nil), (long)quizNumber];
```

I have added localization which works fine in French case but in Chinese '%ld' comes on the screen.

If I put the chinese string in place of english string, I get error
 "data argument not used by format string"

Any pointers? Should I use some kind of encoding?

Comment: I think that you are doing it wrong. You want `self.title.text = NSLocalizedString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%ld", (long)quizNumber], nil);`

Comment: @Larme Your statement does not compile!

Comment: `NSString *translationKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%ld", (long)quizNumber]; self.title.text = NSLocalizedString(translationKey, nil);`?

Comment: Tried. Did not work. In fact this gives the english string because %ld is substituted before localization

Comment: However, if %ld is in the starting of the string then it is translated perfectly to chinese.

Comment: Could you show what's your Localizable.strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done localisation in my app in Chinese as well, no problem so far, but I use mostly %d, not %ld.

Can you try using %d instead?

```
self.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Q%d", nil), (int)quizNumber];
```

Take a look at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Thanks! :D Now I will change all the strings!